Browser extension for browser cache TTL
Is there any software/extension similar to Cache Longer that I can use to extend  the browser cache TTL in brave browser.
The reason I haven't switched to Firefox yet is that it doesn't have the Marvellous Suspender browser extension.
I tried adjusting the browser cache TTL in Firefox based on the idea from 'Make Firefox fast again

I don't have an answer for your question, but if a lack of Marvellous Suspender is keeping you from switching to Firefox, I can recommend these 3 Firefox extensions with similar functionality: Total Suspender: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/total-suspender/ - Tab Unloader: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-unloader-we/ - Sleep Mode: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/sleep-mode/
